# How to compare to abstract enums?

Tags: java, enumeration, organization

I'm working on a searching / organizational algorithm. I use multiple `enum`'s to define every piece of data that I would want to organize. For example:

```
enum CarType implements SearchFactor {
    CAR, SUV, TRUCK, SEMI, LIMO;
    @Override public SearchFactor getSearchFactor() { return this; }
}
```

and

```
enum PaintColor implements SearchFactor {
    BLACK, WHITE, BLUE, GRAY, RED;
    @Override public SearchFactor getSearchFactor() { return this; }
}
```

where `SearchFactor` is:

```
interface SearchFactor { }
```

and a sample data class would be:

```
class Vehicle {
    CarType type = CarType.CAR;
    PaintColor color = PaintColor.BLACK;
}
```

Now for the organization part, I just create an array of included `SearchFactor`'s and add the enum of what `SearchFactor` I would like the algorithm to follow. This is done by incrementally walking through an array of `Vehicle`s and comparing the `Vehicle`s `type` and `color` to the array of included `SearchFactor`s. For example:

```
Vehicle[] getVehicleFromSearchFactor(SearchFactor[] factors) {
    ArrayList<Vehicle> factoredVehicles = new ArrayList<Vehicle>();
    for (Vehicle v : getListOfVehicles()) {
        for (SearchFactor f : factors) {
            if (v.type == f || v.color == f) {
                factoredVehicles.add(v);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return factoredVehicles;
}
```

Is this good practice? Is this too abstract?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the point of a `getSearchFactor()` method which only is implemented as `return this`?

It is not even used in your `getVehicleFromSearchFactor` method.

Other than this, why not. Just make sure that `==` is the right way to compare your search factors. For `enum`s this is fine, but for other objects `.equals(...)` might be better ... or even `.appliesTo(...)` or such.

(Of course, your search in this way allows about no indexing, and has O(number of vehicles × number of search factors) time complexity.)

Comment: Ya, realized the point (lack thereof) of `getsearchFactor` while out at lunch. What do you mean by 'indexing'?

Comment: Thanks for the link, it was helpful. One last thing, if you don't mind. Do you have any suggestions on how to optimize the search to anything better than O(N * SF)?

Comment: This depends a bit on your use cases. As one example, you could have `EnumMap<PaintColor, List<Vehicle>>` and `EnumMap<CarType, List<Vehicle>>`, or a general `HashMap<SearchFactor, List<Vehicle>>`, where you can lookup all vehicles which have a certain color/type/searchFactor.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Thanks for the pointer. Hah, I didn't even know about `EnumMap`. Again thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with answer above re: "getSearchFactor()" method.

In addition to answer above, it seems to me this might be better handled through whatever persistence layer you might be using or some additional indexing technology such as Lucene/Solr.